# Packing squares with shortest string

Tags: geometry

What is the shortest way to enclose $n$ squares? I see that it is said to be difficult to determine the smallest square that encloses squares in general ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_packing_in_a_square)). So I was wondering what about a string. Is there an easy way to find it?

Here are some examples of what I could find. I also considered oblique squares, but as far as I could consider, the shortest was the horizontal.
[image: some examples]

Comment: The way you have arranged it , it will tend to **"Packing Inside A Circle"** , where the radius can be calculated. We can calculate the length of the string too. We can try inverting the Issue : Check the maximum number of Squares in a Circle.

Comment: Interesting question, I saw your wikipedia link, thanks for the context

Answer (score 2):

We are looking for the minimum perimeter for the convex hull of $n$ disjoint unit squares. We have a clear lower bound of $2\sqrt{n\pi}$, the circumference of a circle with area $n$. In order to stay within this circle as much as possible, we need to arrange the squares in parallel rows as in a regular tiling, except that some rows may be offset. (I have no formal proof of this claim, though it seems to be readily apparent.) For an upper bound, my observations suggest that the centers of the squares will remain with the circle. If this is true, then a circle with diameter $\sqrt{2}$ units more than that of the circle with area $n$ will fully enclose the squares, providing an upper bound of $2\sqrt{n\pi}+\pi\sqrt{2}$.

Links previously posted in comments include [optimal values](https://pastebin.com/NBHNpRgj) for $n<100$ as found by a programmed search, and an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGd1q.png) showing arrangements I found manually. Note: Values for $49$ and $50$ are not optimal in the linked image. The correct values for these and a few other optimal arrangements are shown below.

[image]

Comment: Nicely done—not the “easy way to find it” OP was hoping for, perhaps, but a good setting of boundaries.  I was wondering if the minimum perimeter would ever have an hypotenuse $>\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$, and now see a pair of $\sqrt 5$ in your figure for $n=100$—first appearing for $n=92$, I think. Also, $\frac{\sqrt {17}}{2}$ for $n=500$, and $\sqrt {10}$ and $\frac{\sqrt {29}}{2}$ for $n=1000$. Is there a limit to the size of these surds? If the lower bound for the width of the figure $2r$ is $2\sqrt \frac{n}{\pi}$, then does the ratio of least perimeter to width get arbitrarily close to $\pi$?’

Comment: @EdwardPorcella Thank you. Yes, the ratio does get arbitrarily close to $\pi$. No, there is no limit to the size of the surds, but they grow very slowly as the largest is proportional to the fourth root of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The following corrected and revised "String Theory" seems a good method for finding the shortest string to enclose $n$ squares.

Let $s$ denote the minimum string length that can contain $n$ unit squares. For the first few $n$:$$\begin{array}{cc|cc|cc} n & s & n & s & n & s\\\hline 1 & 4 & 17 & 11+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5 & 33 & 17+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5\\2 & 6 & 18 & 12+2\sqrt 5&34 & 18+2\sqrt5\\3 & 5+\sqrt 5 & 19 & 15+\sqrt 5 & 35 & 21+\sqrt5\\4 & 8 & 20 & 11+2\sqrt2+\sqrt13 & 36 & 16+2\sqrt13\\5 & 7+\sqrt 5 & 21 & 12+4\sqrt2 & 37 & 17+2\sqrt2+\sqrt{13}\\6 & 10 & 22 & 13+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5 & 38 & 18+4\sqrt2\\7 & 6+2\sqrt 5 & 23 & 14+2\sqrt 5 & 39 & 19+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5\\8 & 9+\sqrt 5 & 24 & 17+\sqrt 5 & 40 & 20+2\sqrt5\\9 & 12 & 25 & 13+2\sqrt2+\sqrt{13} & 41 & 23+\sqrt5\\10 & 8+2\sqrt 5 & 26 & 14+4\sqrt2 & 42 & 17+2\sqrt5+\sqrt13\\11 & 11 +\sqrt 5 & 27 & 15+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5 & 43 & 18+2\sqrt{13}\\12 & 8+4\sqrt2 & 28 & 16+2\sqrt 5 & 44 & 19+2\sqrt2+\sqrt{13}\\13 & 9+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5 & 29 & 19+\sqrt 5 & 45 & 20+4\sqrt2\\14 & 10+2\sqrt 5 & 30 & 14+2\sqrt{13} & 46 & 21+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5\\15 & 13+\sqrt 5 & 31 & 15+2\sqrt2+\sqrt{13} & 47 & 22+2\sqrt5\\16 & 10+4\sqrt2 & 32 & 16+4\sqrt2 & 48 & 25+\sqrt5\\\end{array}$$

The sample indicates:

**1)** $s$ is an integer, namely $4,\, 8,\, 12$, only for the first three $n=k^2$ , and integer $6,\, 10$ only for the first two $n=k(k+1)$. Every later  $n=k^2$ and $n=k(k+1)$ begins a sequence for which $s$ is an integer $r$ plus a fixed irrational quantity.

But before considering these we note three pairs of sequences from the sample.

**2a)** First, sequences$$n=m(m+2)=3,\ 8,\ 15,\ 24,\ 35,\ 48,\ ...$$ and$$n=m(m+3)+1=5,\ 11,\ 19,\ 29,\ 41,\ ...$$(Here and in all that follows, $m\ge 1$).

In both sequences, if the table is correct, $s=r+\sqrt5$. In the first sequence$$r=5,\ 9,\ 13,\ 17,\ ... =4m+1$$In the second sequence$$r=7,\ 11,\ 15,\ 19,\ ...=4m+3$$Thus $s$ is easily calculated for all $n$ in these sequences.

**2b)** Next, for sequences$$n=m^2+4m+2=7,\ 14,\ 23,\ 34,\ 47,\ ...$$and$$n=m^2+5m+4=10,\ 18,\ 28,\ 40,\ ...$$the table indicates $s=r+2\sqrt5$, and $$r=6,\ 10,\ 14,\ 18,\ ... =4m+2$$and$$r=8,\ 12,\ 16,\ 20,\ ...=4m+4$$respectively.

**2c)** And finally, for sequences$$n=13,\ 22,\ 33,\ 46,\ ... =m^2+6m+5$$and$$n=17,\ 27,\ 39,\ ... =m^2+7m+9$$we have $s=r+2\sqrt2+\sqrt5$, and$$r=9,\ 13,\ 17,\ 21,\ ...=4m+5$$and$$r=11,\ 15,\ 19,\ ...=4m+7$$respectively.

An illustrated example will clarify this. In the diagrams below, of $s$ for the sequence $n=m^2+6m+5=13,\ 22,\ 33$ just noticed, the shape with minimum string perimeter $s$ consists of a rectangle $ABCD,\ EFGH,\ JKLM,\ $ whose breadth exceeds its height by $2$, with remaining squares above and below either equal in number or, as in this case, differing in number by $1$. The height and breadth of each figure are thus equal here, although in three of the six sequences they differ by $1$. As $m$ increases in the sequence, the horizontal and vertical lengths each increase by $1$, so that the integer part $r$ of string perimeter $s$ increases by $4$, as noted in the sequences already considered. But the irrational part of $s$ is fixed for the sequence.
[image: n=13, 22, 33]

**3)** So far, then, we have a way to calculate non-integer $s$, not only for twenty-seven of the forty-eight $n$ in the sample, but for the indefinitely many $n$ in the above six sequences not included in the sample. Remaining $n$ all belong in sequences beginning with $k(k+1)$ or $k^2$. The first non-integer $s$ for $n=k(k+1)$ occurs when $n=3\cdot4=12$, and in the sequence$$n=12,\ 21,\ 32,\ 45,\ ...=m^2+6m+5$$the table above shows $s=r+4\sqrt2$, and$$r=8,\ 12,\ 16,\ 20,\ ...=4m+4$$And $s=r+4\sqrt2$ likewise in the companion sequence beginning with the first $n=k^2$ for which $s$ is non-integer:$$n=16,\ 26,\ 38,\ ...=m^2+7m+8$$and$$r=10,\ 14,\ 18,\ ...=4m+6$$
**4)** The array below illustrates that, except for the five $n$ having integer $s$, each of the first forty-eight $n$ belongs in one of thirteen sequences expressible as a function of $m$. In each sequence, $s=r\ +$ a fixed irrational quantity (see table above), and $r$ is likewise a known function of $m$. Except for the six sequences beginning with $3,\ 5,\ 7,\ 10,\ 13,\ 17$, those remaining, and it seems all subsequent sequences, begin with $n=k(k+1)$ or $n=k^2$.
$$\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccc}\\1&2&3&5&7&10&12&13&16&17&20&25&30&36&42\\4&6&8&11&14&18&21&22&26&27&31&37&43&-&-\\9& &15&19&23&28&32&33&38&39&44&-&-&-&-\\ & &24&29&34&40&45&46&-&-&-&-&-&-&-\\ &  &35&41&47&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-\\ & &48&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&-&\end{array}$$I have checked many but not all of these against diagrams, and find the remaining sequences begun in the sample are:$$n=20,\ 31,\ 44,\ 59,\ ...=m^2+8m+11$$$$n=25,\ 37,\ 51,\ 67,\ ...=m^2+9m+15$$$$n=30,\ 43,\ 58,\ 75,\ ...=m^2+10m+19$$$$n=36,\ 50,\ 66,\ 84,\ ...=m^2+11m+24$$$$n=42,\ 57,\ 74,\ 93,\ ...=m^2+12m+29$$and in each sequence the irrational quantity is as seen in the first array above, and$$r=11,\ 15,\ 19,\ 23,\ ...=4m+7$$$$k=13,\ 17,\ 21,\ 25,\ ...=4m+9$$$$k=14,\ 18,\ 22,\ 26,\ ...=4m+10$$$$k=16,\ 20,\ 24,\ 28,\ ...=4m+12$$$$k=17,\ 21,\ 25,\ 29,\ ...=4m+13$$respectively.

**5)** It remains, then, to discern the laws governing : $a)$sequences beginning in $k(k+1)$ and $k^2$, and $b)$ the integer $r$ and irrational quantity composing $s$ for each sequence.

For $n=k(k+1)$, with $k\ge 3$, in the expression $n=m^2+am+b$ for each sequence, since $a=6,\ 8,\ 10,\ 12,\ $ for $k=3,\ 4,\ 5,\ 6$, evidently  $a=2k$, and since $b=5,\ 11,\ 19,\ 29=k^2-k-1$, we can construct, for any given $k$, the sequence that begins with $k(k+1)$.

E.g. for $k(k+1)=56=7\cdot8$, the first term of the sequence $n=m^2+am+b$ is$$1^2+2\cdot 7\cdot 1+7^2-7-1=1+14+41=56$$the second term is$$2^2+2\cdot 7\cdot 2+7^2-7-1=4+29+41=73$$the third term is$$3^2+2\cdot 7\cdot 3+ 7^2-7-1=9+42+41=92$$and so on.

Further, since again for $k(k+1)$ with $k=3,\ 4,\ 5,\ 6,\ $ we found (see just above) $r=4m+4,\ 7,\ 10,\ 13$, then generally $r=4m+3k-5$, and we can  say that for each member of the sequence beginning with $n=k(k+1)=56$, $s$ is some given irrational quantity plus $r=4m+3k-5=20,\ 24,\ 28,\ 32$.
The same irrational quantity, as has become clear, is also a component of $s$ for $n=8^2=64$.

**For $n=k(k+1)$, can we express this irrational quantity as a function of $k$?**

Of the figures that give $s$ for $n=k(k+1)=12,\ 20,\ 30,\ 42,\ 56...$, consider the first two. On the left, $n=3\cdot 4=12$ and $k$ is odd; on the right, $n=4\cdot 5=20$ and $k$ is even. The rectangular parts $ABCD$ and $GHJK$ of each figure contain $(k-1)(k+1)=k^2-1$ unit squares, an even number for odd $k$, an odd number for even $k$. The number of squares remaining, then, is$$n-(k-1)(k+1=k(k+1)-k^2-1=k+1$$which is even for odd $k$ and odd for even $k$. Thus for odd $k$ there is an equal number $\frac{k+1}{2}$ of squares above and below the rectangle, as in the example on the left. For even $k$, there are $\frac{k+2}{2}$ squares above the rectangle and $\frac{k}{2}$ below (or vice-versa), as in the example on the right.
[image: n=12 & 20]
For odd $k$, the base $AF$ of the right triangle at each corner of the figure is$$\frac{1}{2}\left(k+1-\frac{k+1}{2}\right)=\frac{k+1}{4}$$the height $FE=1$, and hypotenuse$$AE=\sqrt{\left(\frac{k+1}{4}\right)^2+1^2}$$Therefore, since $k(k+1)$ is first in its sequence $m^2+am+b$, and $r=4m+3k-5=3k-1$ for $m=1$, then for $n=k(k+1)$ and $k$ odd$$s=3k-1+4\sqrt{\left(\frac{k+1}{4}\right)^2+1^2}$$

For even $k$, the base $GM$ of the upper triangle is$$\frac{1}{2}\left(k+1-\frac{k+2}{2}\right)=\frac{k}{4}$$the height $ML=1$, and hypotenuse$$GL=\sqrt{\left(\frac{k}{4}\right)^2+1^2}$$The base $HN$ of the lower triangle is$$\frac{1}{2}\left(k+1-\frac{k}{2}\right)=\frac{k+2}{4}$$making the hypotenuse$$HP=\sqrt{\left(\frac{k+2}{4}\right)^2+1^2}$$Therefore, for $n=k(k+1)$ and $k$ even$$s=3k-1+2\sqrt{\left(\frac{k}{4}\right)^2+1^2}+2\sqrt{\left(\frac{k+2}{4}\right)^2+1^2}$$
Finally, using the method of this section, and the data from the previous section, I find that, for $k\ge 4$, in the sequence $n=m^2+am+b=k^2$, the integer part $r$ of $s$ is $4m+3k-6=3k-2$ for $m=1$. And since, as we have seen, the irrational part of $s$ for $n=k^2$ is the same as that for $n=(k-1)k$, we can calculate $s$ for any given  $n=k^2$.

Comment: Different $n$ cannot have the same $s$. Removing a square around which the string bends will allow for a shorter string. This implies $s_i<s_j$ for all $i<j$ See [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhdML.png) for improvements on $n=12$ and $n=13$. Similar improvement can be made for many of your solutions.

Comment: @DanielMathias, Yes, and $18$ is not a minimum for $n=20$, but rather $12+4\sqrt2$.  $s$ for $n(n+1)$ is not always an integer.  And your claim that different $n$ can't have the same $s$ seems true also.  I need to fix this.

Comment: Here is an [interesting result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXlqy.png): $S_{16}<16$

Comment: @DanielMathias, Yes indeed, the plot thickens--back to "square one"

Comment: @DanielMathias, I've tried to correct and revise.

Comment: Unfortunately, it gets more complicated as $n$ increases. Your formulae provide an upper bound which the minimum is not greater than. The extent of my efforts, [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGd1q.png), shows lower values than most of your results for the same range.

Comment: Still oversimplified I see.  A theory based on bad data won’t do. Your figures too seem to form sequences—columns of regularly increasing integers plus the same irrational part, e.g. for $n=33, 40, 47$ it’s $s=11, 13 , 15 +2\sqrt 2+2\sqrt 5+\sqrt 13$. Do they persist, or is each short-lived? $31$ and $32$ have no descendants. Are they the last of earlier, finite sequences? Can you tell me for which $n$ my number for $s$ first goes wrong? Thanks.

Comment: They do not persist. As $n$ increases, the number of rows also increases. With an increased number of rows, we can have more rows that are narrower than the widest row, providing more non-integer addends. 31 and 32 are indeed the last of their kind: $\{12,16,21,26,32\}$ and $\{20,25,31\}$. The first miss is at $n=19$, for which I have $s=16.892922$ (cf. $30,36,43$). Also note: the solutions shown for $49$ and $50$ are not optimal.

Comment: It's exactly as you say.  With much help from your image I back-filled the figures for $n<30$.  I first went astray at $n=19$.  The twelve finite sequences having the same irrational part seem to be $\{3, 5, 8, 11\}$, $\{7, 10, 14, 18, 23\}$, $\{12, 16, 21, 26, 32\}$, $\{13, 17, 22, 27\}$, $\{15, 20, 25, 31\}$, $\{19, 24,  30, 36, 43, 50\}$, $\{28, 34, 41, 48\}$, $\{29, 35, 42, 49\}$, $\{33, 40, 47\}$, $\{37, 44\}$, $\{38, 45\}$, $\{39, 46\}$.  I assume the last few have more members  in them $>50$. Thanks for  helping me sort it out this far.

Comment: I have automated the task. Optimal values for $n<100$ can be found [here.](https://pastebin.com/NBHNpRgj)

Comment: @DanielMathias I appreciate your work on computing the optimal values. I was wondering if you took into account the case of a tilted square. Do you think this could change the minimum value in any way?

Comment: As your list confirms, $27$ doesn't belong where I put it but goes here: $\{27, 33, 40, 47, 55\}$.  A pattern I was groping for now works: $n$ consecutive figures have breadth=height=$n$, e.g. $27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32$ have breadth=height=$6$. A better solution for $49$ is $11+2\sqrt 2+4\sqrt 5+\sqrt {13}$, the first $8$ by $8$ figure. So $49$ is not last in the $\{29, 35, 42\}$ sequence but first in a new one.  The solution for $50$, $12+4\sqrt 2+4\sqrt 5$ also begins a new one. Between the $k$ figures that are $k$-wide and $k$-tall, those that are $k$ by $k+1$ number $1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5$?